# Serialize decimals in scrapinghub

Tags: scrapy, scrapinghub

I'm following the documentation about serializers in this [link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html?highlight=serializer), I'm not sure if there's lack of documentation regarding on decimal serializers ?. I defined an Item with a scrapy field like this:

`prize = scrapy.Field(serializer=Decimal, output_processor=TakeFirst())`

I'm getting several errors when scrapinhub stores this value, especially with numbers containing commas.

Is there any standard method for serializing decimals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a `scrapinghub`, or `scrapy` error, you cannot convert a strings with comma into a number, you'll first have to remove that comma and then convert:

```
def decimal_serializer(value):
    return float(value.replace(',', ''))

...

    prize = scrapy.Field(serializer=decimal_serializer, output_processor=TakeFirst())
```